# Why did emacs doesn't have scroll one line keybinding?

Tags: emacs

I am switching from vim to emacs. I have been using vim for two years, so when i editing with emacs i always thinking about the way i used with vim.
Vim got quite a few keybinding to scroll buffer, one line, half screen, page up and so on. But emacs can only scroll a page with <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>. Yes, i can define a custom keybinding to scroll one line by myself easily, but what i thinking now is whether i should do this. If it is a really necessary fundamental keybinding, then emacs must got by default.

Don't you feel getting lost where the line is when you enter <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>

Comment: The default settings are based on the idea that redrawing the terminal contents unnecessarily is an undesirable and annoying expense (with line-by-line scrolling being the worst case of that, of course). That's typically no longer an issue, but I think this is just one of those things where most users are either accustomed to the defaults, or have added custom functions to scroll the way they prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel lost, try setting `scroll-preserve-screen-position` to `1`:

```
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 1)
```

You can either add that line to your init file to make it permanent or press <kbd>M-:</kbd> and enter it at the prompt to try it out in the current session.

Also, if you find yourself missing vim a lot in general, you can always use e.g. [evil-mode](https://gitorious.org/evil/pages/Home). Remember, though, that *emacs is not vi*, and if you really want to switch and use it as your main editor you will only benefit if you stop thinking too much about what you are used to doing in vim.

Comment: Good idea. I am feel better now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to try `CTRL-N`.

Comment: Yes, but with <kbd>CTRL-N</kdb> i need to move cursor to the bottom of the screen, and then i can start to scroll. I think it's not very effecient.

Comment: @ccheng Use `M-r` to quickly move point (cursor) to center, top, and bottom of the window. Once point is where you want it, you can use `C-l` to move the current *line* to the center/top/bottom of the window (which constitutes another way of scrolling in smaller steps).

Answer (score 0):

You can also scroll using a mouse wheel. Depending on your settings for that, it can easily scroll one line at a time. Just another possibility to mention.